# flip image in every 5 sec

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am fliping the images on mouse over. i want to flip images in every 5 sec automatic. i am new in javascript. so any one can help me it will be great

```css
 #f1_container {
   position: relative;
   margin: 10px auto;
   width: 450px;
   height: 281px;
   z-index: 1;
 }
 #f1_container {
   perspective: 1000;
 }
 #f1_card {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
   transition: all 1.0s linear;
 }
 #f1_container:hover #f1_card {
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
   box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
 }
 .face {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
 }
 .face.back {
   display: block;
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 10px;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #aaa;
 }
```

```html
<div class="work">
  <a href="inner.html">
    <div id="f1_container">
      <div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
        <div class="front face">
          <img src="img/work1.jpg" class="bottom" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="back face center">
          <img src="img/work2.jpg" class="top" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

on mouse its working fine . but i want auto flip in every 5 sec

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `setInterval()`

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    // Function goes here
}, 5000);
```

It loops a function every 5000 milliseconds.

---

In your situation you're already using `:hover` to change the css, change this `:hover` to a `class`. Now you can `toggleClass()` on an object with jQuery, so it gets removed if it's there, and added if it's not there.

**This CSS**

```
#f1_container:hover #f1_card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
```

**Becomes:**

```
.flipped { 
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
```

**And your jQuery:**

```
window.setInterval(function() { //setInterval (loop a function)
    $("#f1_card").toggleClass("flipped"); //toggle class "flipped"
}, 5000); // Loop it every 5000 milliseconds
```

**JavaScript:**

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("f1_card").classList.toggle("flipped");
}, 5000)
```

Every 5000 milliseconds you toggle the class `flipped` on `#f1_card`, so that it flips back and forth.

---

**Explanation**

Let's break down what we did, we changed the `:hover` to a `class` because instead of making it occur on hover we want to make it occur by `toggleClass()` every 5000 milliseconds (we use the `setInterval()` function for this).

Comment: i am new in javascript can you tell me which function should be writen there . i want same effect which is on mouse over

Comment: @Rohit I enhanced my answer for you.